Migration of local user policy settings and OS services settings
I’m trying to figure out how to handle local policy settings and service configurations on Windows 7, 10, and 11. Here's the situation:
I have local policy settings applied to a specific user  (operator1) on one computer, and I need to export these settings. I also need to export some system service settings.
Then, I need to apply the policy settings to a different user (operator5) on another computer, along with those exported service configurations.
I know that local policy settings are in C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy, and some parts are stored in the registry, but I’m not sure how to isolate the settings for a specific user and move them over.
Has anyone done this before?
Are there built-in tools or scripts that can help with this?
Are there any "gotchas" I should watch out for when transferring these settings to another machine?

Local policy does not have settings specific to users as with Group Policy. User settings apply to all users.

@GregAskew I may have phrased the question wrong, but then how do you configure local group policies for a user via mmc? I can configure from under Administrator restrictions for Operator1 only, but they don't apply to other users

Probably help to know what settings.
